# Difference b/w CURRENTTIMESTAMP and CURRENTTIMESTAMP() in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to compare DB schema of two different database and I used MySQL workbench "compare database" option to compare the schema. It gave a report saying the list of differences. There are some changes in the TIMESTAMP field and I noticed that one has default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and another one has CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). On a high-level, I know both are similar. But I'm too curious to find is there any difference b/w those.

Comment: From User Manual: *CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() are synonyms for NOW().* So no difference except the code length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add precision using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Example :

```
select current_timestamp;    -- 2020-05-11 23:11:27
select current_timestamp(2); -- 2020-05-11 23:11:31.48
```

Comment: That is interesting.  In the rest of the programming world, this is the difference between a function call (w/ parenthesis) and a function reference (w/o parenthesis).  I guess I have a lot to learn when it comes to SQL.

Comment: Good one @antonie.lange.

Comment: @imnickvaughn - This quirk _may_ be specific to MySQL.